# LINQ query return Grandparent, Parent, Grandchild where Grandchild has value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm building a system for producing surveys and handling the responses, I have a viewmodel SurveyTakeViewModel

```
namespace Survey.ViewModel
{
     public class SurveyTakeViewModel
     {
         public Models.Survey Survey { get; set; }
         public bool TakenBefore { get; set; }
     }
 }

namespace Survey.Models
{
    public class Survey
    {
        [Key]
        public int SurveyId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public string MessageStart { get; set; }
        public string MessageEnd { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Question> Question { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Survey.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
         public virtual int SurveyId { get; set; }

         [Key]
         public int QuestionId { get; set; }
         public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
         public string QuestionText { get; set; }
         public string QuestionNote { get; set; }
         public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }

         public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<QuestionAnswerOption> QuestionAnswerOption{ get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswer { get; set; }
     }
 }

 namespace Survey.Models
 {
     public class QuestionAnswer
     {
         public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }

         [Key]
         public int QuestionAnswerId { get; set; }
         public int SurveyId { get; set; }
         public string UserId { get; set; }
         public string QuestionActualResponse { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

It all works fine for the questionnaire, however when a user revisits a questionnaire they have previously answered I want to populate the QuestionAnswer part of the viewmodel with answers only by a specific userid, at the moment I get everyanswer. I have tried loads of different Linq queries, initially my ICollections<> were List<>, which I am told could cause all records to be returned.

at the moment I am using

```
Survey = db.Survey.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyId == 1)
```

which returns all QuestionAnswer

I have tried things like

```
Survey = db.Survey.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Question
.Any(b => b.QuestionAnswer
.Any(c => c.UserId == userId)));
```

but it still returns all QuestionAnswer for every userId

Comment: What do you need? The answer for one survey of one user?

Comment: yes please, at the moment I get all QuestionAnswers for survey one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you know which survey you want, but when you access the various properties, they are populating with extra information... you'd like fewer grandchild records.

I don't know enough LinqToEntities to limit the loading in the way that is needed (LinqToSql would use `DataLoadOptions.LoadsWith` and `DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith`).  Instead, I offer this manual shaping of the data - after loading.  Perhaps it will help an expert understand the question and then they can express it in a LinqToEntities query.

```
int surveyId = GetSurveyId();
int userId = GetUserId();

Survey mySurvey = db.Survey.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyId == surveyId);

ILookup<int, QuestionAnswer> qaLookup = db.QuestionAnswer
  .Where(qa => qa.SurveyId == surveyId && qa.UserId == userId)
  .ToLookup(qa => qa.QuestionId);

foreach(Question q in mySurvey.Questions)
{
  //limit q.QuestionAnswer to only this user's answers.
  q.QuestionAnswer = qaLookup[q.QuestionId].ToList();
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the problem is called by LazyLoading, but can't get my head around getting linq to only include grandchildren from the QuestionAnswer table where a given userId.